# How can I use an element in a list as a parameter in range()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, range, element

So I have a for loop `for i in range(0, arr[0]):` and I want the stop parameter of the `range()` function to be variable based on the value of the first element in an array.  When I do this, however, even though the value of `arr[0]` is an integer, python comes back and gives me an error saying `TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`.  How can I either convert this element in the list to an integer or find another way to use its value as a parameter?

I am also using this same value to increment and decrement variables within this loop.

Thanks!

Full Code:

```
def diagonalDifference(arr):
    stopInt = arr[0]
    primary = 0
    secondary = 0
    pArrIndex = 1
    sArrIndex = -1
    for i in range(0, stopInt):
        primary += arr[pArrIndex]
        pArrIndex += arr[0]
    for i in range(0, stopInt):
        secondary += arr[sArrIndex]
        sArrIndex -= arr[0]
    return abs(primary - secondary)
```

This is for a challenge [here](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/diagonal-difference/problem?h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen)

The purpose of the diagonalDifference function can be found in that link.

Comment: Can you show your problem in a runnable example? You can see [here](https://www.ideone.com/ruc0ej) it can run fine, so it depends on the rest of your code.

Comment: That error message means that `arr[0]` is actually a list, not a number. You should print `arr` to see what it contains.

Comment: Just do `print (type(arr[0]))` and you will get your answer

Comment: @PM2Ring `[[11, 2, 4], [4, 5, 6], [10, 8, -12]]` is the result

Comment: `arr[0]` is `[11, 2, 4]` in your case. How can you then use it in range? You need `for i in range(0, arr[0][0]):` perhaps

Comment: Ok, so you have a list of 3 lists. Do you want to use the 1st number of the 1st list as your range stop arg? If so, Bazingaa's code is the solution.

Comment: @Jodast it is a list then

Comment: Hmm. There are a few related issues with that `diagonalDifference` function. You should explain in your question (not here in the comments) what it's supposed to do, and the desired output for the `arr` that you just posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
def diagonalDifference(arr):
     a=sum(v[i] for i,v in enumerate(arr))
     b=sum(v[-i] for i,v in enumerate(arr,1))
     return abs(a - b)
```

I did this because i read the Hacker-rank challenge

Comment: Thank you, can you explain how this works though?  I don't understand how this works.

Comment: @Jodast I use `enumerate` and the first value `i` will be `0,1,2..` in `a` so get second value `v` which is the list values to get there index of `i`, then same think with be just do negatively and start from one as from the second argument of `enumerate`, then do `abs` for `a` and `b`